# Access Azure Function runtime settings

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

Is it possible to access/update the [Web.config used by WebJobs.Script.WebHost](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/Web.config) or the `func.exe.Config` (in `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.0-beta.91\`)?

When I create an Azure Function using the Consumption plan and browse the file share, I do not see either of these files in any of the directories, but I'm assuming that the runtime is getting the settings from one of these files, or something similar.

Essentially, I would like to [remove the standard .NET headers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/removing-standard-server-headers-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) being returned by setting some values in one of these .config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way for you to modify the web.config used by the Functions runtime. I've opened a tracking item in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1237) for us to investigate if we can open this up for configurability.