# Azure Functions NodeJs: Remove Http Response Header

Tags: node.js, azure, http-headers, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I have an HTTP triggered, NodeJs Azure Function, and I'm looking to remove the "X-Powered-By" header from my response, but have found no way to do so.

I've tried adding both [this](https://github.com/gregjhogan/remove-insecure-response-headers-site-extension) and [this](https://github.com/tjrobinson/RemoveCustomHeaders) azure site extensions, but neither has worked for me,

Setting the response header manually, i.e. `res.headers = { ['x-powered-by']: null }` is ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments made on this github issue: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/290 it would seem that using either extension should have removed the headers you wanted.

Modifying the response headers will likely won't work as they are probably added further down the pipeline by the function host and not overridable, see:
[Access Azure Function runtime settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42445686/access-azure-function-runtime-settings)

Azure functions recently removed the `x-aspnet-version` header, further removal of other headers is tracked as part of the `azure-webjobs-script-sdk` [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1237)

You should leave a comment on the github issue and you can further discuss with the team working on this.

Comment: I've added a comment on the issue.

Comment: Note that deployment of the removal of the `X-ASPNet-Version` header is not yet complete. This should happen by Tuesday or Wednesday. https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/79

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension called Remove Custom Headers that works for Web Apps but not for functions that have their own resource group. So, what you can do is:
1. Create a regular Web App
2. Create a function and make sure you use the same Hosting Plan as the Web App (do not use Consumption). 
3. Once the function is created, install the extension named: "Remove Custom Headers"
4. Restart the function and the headers (Server and X-Powered-By) should disappear.